# Matlab: Efficient image patch extraction

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing

I have a large set of images from which I wish to extract image patches from. The patches are uniform in size and extracted from each image at regular grid points. I can do this with the following code:

```
for n = 1:nImages
    % Read image
    imageFile = imageFiles{n};
    I = imread(imageFile);

    % Grid point locations
    height = size(I, 1);
    width = size(I, 2);
    border = floor(patchSize/2);
    centres = gridPoints(height, width, nPointsX, nPointsY, border);

    % Extract and process patches
    for p = 1:nPatches
        % Patch location
        x = centres(p, 1);
        y = centres(p, 2);
        % Top-left point of patch
        x = x - floor(patchSize/2) + 1;
        y = y - floor(patchSize/2) + 1;

        % Extract patch -- BOTTLENECK!
        patch = imcrop(I, [x y patchSize-1 patchSize-1]);

        % Process patch
        % ...
    end
end
```

This code is highly inefficient, especially given both the large number of images and the large number of grid points (I am also doing this at different scales for each image). I have run Matlab's profiler and found that imcrop is the cause of this inefficiency. Running on only 50 images (but with 100 x 100 grid points at 3 scales) took 756 seconds.

Is there an alternative way to extract image patches in Matlab without incurring such a huge processing overhead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subscript indexing is a natural operation in MATLAB.

```
patch = I(y:y+patchSize-1, x:x+patchSize-1);
```

Given the counterintuitive use of `imcrop` in the question with `rect = [x y patchSize-1 patchSize-1]` giving a square dimension of `patchSize-1` x `patchSize-1` the output size of the above command should be confirmed as correct for your purposes.

**EDIT**: For RGB (or any planar multi-channel format):

```
patch = I(y:y+patchSize-1, x:x+patchSize-1, :);
```

Comment: Make sure you subtract 1 from `y+patchSize` and `x+patchSize`. But yea, this is the way to go. I've done a decent amount of image processing and I've actually never used `imcrop` before...

Comment: @jucestain: Thanks for the correction.  That's certainly correct if `patchSize` is interpreted as the square patch's dimension, but this result will be different size from the `imcrop` example because `rect(3:4)` are the width and height.  I guess this was just a bug in the OP's code.

Comment: Great, thanks. I assumed imcrop would perform this indexing and that there would be no performance difference. Each image now takes ~1 second rather than ~2 seconds with the imcrop version (using a 100x100 grid of 16x16 pixel patches, with 3 scales per image -- 1, 0.5, 0.25).

Answer (score 1):

you may want to ensure that the patch will never go out of the image boundary:

```
patch = I(max(1,y):min(y+patchSize-1,size(I,1)), max(1,x):min(x+patchSize-1,size(I,2)), :);
```